# Sum two dates in Java

Tags: java, date, calendar

How can I add two dates in Java?

Example: The sum of  "2010-01-14 19:16:17" "0000-10-03 01:10:05"
would result in "2010-11-17 20:26:22".

I know how to do it using Calendar and adding field by field.

Is any other way to sum them all (year/month/day/hour/minute/second) at once?

Comment: How can the sum of two calendar dates be in any way meaningful? (If you're trying to add an interval, this seems an odd way of storing the data.)

Comment: @Diego: Take this example - what would expect to be the answer to "3 May 2009" + "23 Jul 1984"? The question makes no sense, and neither does the answer.

Comment: From his example, he wants to add a date and and interval. He has a clear and valid intention, he just worded his question imprecisely. I can live with that.

Comment: @Carl - Totally, it just seems like an odd way of storing the interval. (Just thinking about the future legibility of the code, but it's most likely not an issue in this instance.)

Comment: It's not his fault that the standard (!) Java library's date handling is so horribly dysfunctional. But if he wants to work more extensively with dates, times and intervals then I indeed second the suggestion of Joda time.

Comment: I've tried to clarify this issue a little more in my answer.

Comment: @Diego - `"0000-10-03 01:10:05"` is not valid for GregorianCalendar: there in no year number 0

Comment: Mind coming back to this question and reevaulating the accepted answer?  Java's changed quite a lot since you asked this and there are better approaches to doing this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using the Date object, you can just do:

```
Date d1 = ...
Date d2 = ...

long sum = d1.getTime() + d2.getTime();

Date sumDate = new Date(sum);
```

The code uses the `.getTime()` method that returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch. 
Needless to say the `Date` class has a lot of problems and should be avoided when possible.

Do you want to sum other types instead?

Update: for `Calendar`, I would do the following (based on javadocs):

```
Calendar c1 = ...
Calendar c2 = ...
long sum = c1.getTimeInMillis() + c2.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar sumCalendar = (Calendar)c1.clone();
sumCalendar.setTimeInMillis(sum);
```

UPDATED: As Steve stated, this works if the Date you presented here assumes that the second date is with respect to the Java epoch.  If you do want to start with year "0", then you need to account for that (by subtracting your epoch time).

Comment: This is just incorrect. Java's epoch is 1970. So using Date to represent a time duration (such as 0000-00-00 00:01 for one minute) will not work. Just try it and see.

Comment: Example: 1970-00-00 00:00 = 0 msec, so adding 1970-00-00 00:00 to 1970-00-00 00:00 using your algorithm yields 1970-00-00 00:00, where as the OP expects it to be 3940-00-00 00:00.

Comment: I store date/time as long so I just have to use + ;) No need to convert to Date/Calender and back again.

Comment: As @Steve points out you cannot add two dates as the result is meaningless, You can add an interval to a date to get another date.

Comment: @Peter.  I cannot recommend using proper datatype classes for non-primitive concepts enough.  Consider using jodatime or your own libary (if possible).

Comment: @notnoop You are correct in most use cases. however in my case, 1) all our date-imes are in GMT 2) performance is an issue and we want to minimise or eliminate any object creation. As such all my date time operations, including parsing and outputting, can be performed without object creation.

Comment: This solution is so wrong as a general solution. This works only in the example that was in the question.

Answer (score 12):

Don't sum the time in millis of the two dates!

```
Date d1 = new Date();
Date d2 = new Date();
Date dTotal = new Date(d1.getTime() + d2.getTime());
System.out.println(dTotal); // Incorrect! Misses about 1970 years.
```

Just clone the `Calendar` and add the datetime parts one by one.

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cTotal = (Calendar) c1.clone();
cTotal.add(Calendar.YEAR, c2.get(Calendar.YEAR));
cTotal.add(Calendar.MONTH, c2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1); // Months are zero-based!
cTotal.add(Calendar.DATE, c2.get(Calendar.DATE));
cTotal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
cTotal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
cTotal.add(Calendar.SECOND, c2.get(Calendar.SECOND));
cTotal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, c2.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
System.out.println(cTotal.getTime()); // Correct!
```

Needless to say, JodaTime is smarter and cleaner with this.

Comment: not sure if the Calendar solution works (despite OP wrote that he knows how to do it). The problem with Calendar: there is no year 0 (and missing treatment of *negative* years - when ERA == BC)

Answer (score 10):

As always, I would recommend the Java 8 date/time APIs or [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for date/time work, since they are *much* more powerful and intuitive.

You can add durations and periods to a [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object trivially. You can add minutes/seconds/months equally easily.

However, you *can't* add two dates directly, since that doesn't really make sense. This is a powerful illustration of why Joda is a help - it stops you doing stuff that you really shouldn't be doing.

Comment: I don't like fascistic/paternalistic/communistic features of languages designed to stop me from doing what they think I shouldn't do because many times I need to do things that they think I shouldn't do.

Comment: Joda is a library, not a language.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime later = 
    LocalDateTime
    .parse ( 
        "2010-01-14 19:16:17"
        .replace ( " " , "T" ) 
    )
    .plus( Period.parse ( "P10M3D" ) )
    .plus( Duration.parse ( "PT1H10M5S" ) ) 
;
```

## ISO 8601

The representation of a span-of-time using the same format as a moment is creating confusion. A span is not at all the same as a moment.

Instead of using `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS` format for a span of time, I suggest using the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of [PnYnMnDTnHnMnS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). In this format, the `P` marks the beginning (for "Period" presumably) and the `T` separates the years-month-days portion from the hours-minutes-seconds portion.

Example values:

- `PT1H30M` → One and a half hours.
- `P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S` → Three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds.
- `P10M3DT1H10M5S` → Your Question’s duration of `0000-10-03 01:10:05`.

## java.time

The Question and the other Answers use troublesome old date-time classes now outmoded by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing and generating Strings that represent date-time values.

The Question does not provide any time zone info, so here we use the [`LocalDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class. If we know an offset-from-UTC we would use the `OffsetDateTime` class, and if even better we knew a time zone, we would use the `ZonedDateTime` class.

Spans of time in java.time are divided amongst a pair of classes. Years-months-days are represented by the [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class, and hours-minutes-seconds are handled by the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class.

Combining these times, we can indeed perform date-time math. Here we add a span of time to an starting date-time to get a resulting date-time. And we do so in very few lines of code. The result is indeed that expected by the Question.

We convert the input strings to canonical ISO 8601 format by replacing the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( "2010-01-14 19:16:17".replace ( " " , "T" ) );
//"0000-10-03 01:10:05"
Period period = Period.parse ( "P10M3D" );
Duration duration = Duration.parse ( "PT1H10M5S" );
LocalDateTime result = ldt.plus ( period ).plus ( duration );
```

Compare to the result expected in the Question.

```
LocalDateTime expectation = LocalDateTime.parse ( "2010-11-17 20:26:22".replace ( " " , "T" ) );
Boolean isSame = result.equals ( expectation );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "ldt: " + ldt + " + period: " + period + " + duration: " + duration + " is result: " + result + " compared to expectation: " + expectation + " is the same: " + isSame );
```

> ldt: 2010-01-14T19:16:17 + period: P10M3D + duration: PT1H10M5S is result: 2010-11-17T20:26:22 compared to expectation: 2010-11-17T20:26:22 is the same: true

Answer (score 3):

You want to do `getTimeInMillis()` on both those Calendars so you'll have two honest-to-goodness `long` values you can add up. You can then take the sum and stash it in a new Calendar using that Calendar's `setTimeInMillis()` method.

Whether you want to add two `Calendar`s as shown above or two `Date`s as shown in notnoop's answer is up to you, of course. The effect is similar, it just depends on what you want to do with the result. A `Date` is mostly just good for storing and/or converting to a String for printing out or displaying, whereas a `Calendar` will let you fiddle with the individual time values should you so choose.

As others have mentioned, you're committing some conceptual no-no's in using a `Date` or `Calendar`, which are meant to store "real" dates and times, e.g. ones in the 20th or 21st century, as intervals, i.e. time spans. The classes in the standard Java library don't give you really useful tools to handle this, which is why the Joda classes were developed. All the cool kids in date/time processing use those; but on the other hand that involves downloading and managing a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2):

notnoop answer is definitely correct. However, if you are going to do lots of processing of dates, times and intervals, I suggest that you look at class DateUtils in [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) and at [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.

JDK7 will come with better support for some of the features that joda-time provides. Just saying ... it might be a consideration if your app makes heavy usage of this stuff.

Comment: +1 I strongly recommend joda-time.  My impression is that the Time/Date API in Java 7 is basically dead!  Do you know what the progress is?

Comment: I believe that JSR310 is dead wrt. Java 7, yes. There's a question on SO somewhere that recently asked this very question (don't have the link to hand, I'm afraid).

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your EPOCH.  The Java epoch (like Unix) is 1 Jan 1970 GMT/UTC.  I assume you think you're adding ten months, 3 days and some odd hours from 1 Jan 0000 but you have a epoch offset until 1970.  The maths may not necessarily work.

Use Calendar or Joda (as mentioned).  If you just simply want to add a number of seconds and days (&c) then feel free to add said # of milliseconds to your first date object.

Answer (score 0):

Use calendar class add method to add two dates in java.

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.add(Calendar.Date,23);

calendar.add(Calendar.Month,13);

calendar.add(Calendar.Year,15);
```

By using add method in Calendar class we can add day,month,year to the existing date.

[click here for complete program.](https://java-interview-questions.com/how-to-add-two-dates-in-java/)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score -1):

I am occasionally guilty of this practice too, storing time interval in a date object and using getTime() as suggested by notnoop.

It works. Contrary to certain opinion, it certainly works. I just ignore that the interval could be representative of an unintended date. It is a quick and dirty way for me to add an interval, say, [6 years, 6 months, 6 days, 6 hours, 6 minutes, 6 seconds] to a date.