# Adding Time together in java

Tags: java, datetime, time

I am getting rows of Time from Database as Below

```
TimeWorked
09:05:25
09:30:15
10:15:01
08:19:49
09:17:40
```

Now I want to sum up the Time together in java to get **46:28:10**.I tried something using Calendar class but it haven't worked. How to sum up these hours in java

Thanks for Reply

Comment: can you please post what did you try using Calendar? I why didn't it work?

Comment: what code have you written to solve your problem? what are start times? what are end times?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Refer this question on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067657/sum-two-dates-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start your loop of rows get each row in loop and proceed

```
int hour = 0;
int minute = 0;

for(<your row loop>) {
    String[] rowtime= row[i].split(":");
    hour += Integer.parseInt(rowtime[0]);
    minute += Integer.parseInt(rowtime[1]);
}

hour += minute / 60;
minute %= 60;

String result = hour + ":" + minute
```

Comment: You missed one thing.What if the Minute is less than 10 when doing mod 60.I fixed it Thanks any how

Answer (score 3):

If possible in your project, I would suggest you to use JodaTime and the [`Duration`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) class. It will be much easier than using the standard Java Calendar/Date API.

Here another example using the Period class:

```
PeriodFormatter hoursMinutesSecondsFormatter = 
     new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
            .appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":").appendSeconds().toFormatter();
Period period1 = hoursMinutesSecondsFormatter.parseMutablePeriod("09:05:25").toPeriod();
Period period2 = hoursMinutesSecondsFormatter.parseMutablePeriod("09:30:15").toPeriod();
System.out.println(period1.plus(period2).toString(hoursMinutesSecondsFormatter));
```

Prints: 18:35:40

Comment: A comment for the future: This answer is true for all versions of Java up to the current stable version 7. Starting with Java 8 there will be something very similar to JodaTime inside the standard java.

Comment: The Java 8 time API is designed via [JSR-310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) and will be found in [the `java.time` package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] timeWorked = {"09:05:25", "09:30:15"}

int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < timeWorked.length; i++) {
    hours += Integer.parseInt(timeWorked.split(":")[0]);
    minutes += Integer.parseInt(timeWorked.split(":")[1]);
    seconds += Integer.parseInt(timeWorked.split(":")[2]);
}

// Now you have your hours minutes and seconds all added up and all you have to do is do some math similar to what shreyansh jogi said to calculate in hours minutes and seconds.
```

Don't forget to catch NumberFormatExceptions that might be thrown from the parseInt