# Get Average of two java.util.Date

Tags: java, date

I have an array of java.util.Date objects.  I am trying to find the average.

For example, if I have 2 date objects with 7:40AM and 7:50AM.  I should get an average date object of 7:45AM.

The approach I am thinking of is inefficient:

1. for loop through all dates
2. find difference between 0000 and time
3. add that time diff to a total
4. divide that by the total count
5. convert that time to a date object

Is there an easier function to do this?

Comment: sounds good, how about converting all the dates to miliseconds then taking the average and converting it back to a date? (myDate.getTime()+myDate1.getTime())/2

Comment: Waiting for the average date jokes... ok, nvm.  Convert all `Date` objects to milliseconds, take the average, then convert back to a `Date` object.

Comment: The end is near!  2036 soon!

Comment: Note that your *title* refers to two dates, but your *question* refers to an array of them. There's a significant difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well fundamentally you can just add up the "millis since the Unix epoch" of all the `Date` objects and find the average of those. Now the tricky bit is avoiding overflow. Options are:

1. Divide by some known quantity (e.g. 1000) to avoid overflow; this reduces the accuracy by a known amount (in this case to the second) but will fail if you have more than 1000 items
2. Divide each millis value by the number of dates you're averaging over; this will always work, but has hard-to-understand accuracy reduction
3. Use `BigInteger` instead

An example of approach 1:

```
long totalSeconds = 0L;
for (Date date : dates) {
     totalSeconds += date.getTime() / 1000L;
}
long averageSeconds = totalSeconds / dates.size();
Date averageDate = new Date(averageSeconds * 1000L);
```

An example of approach 3:

```
BigInteger total = BigInteger.ZERO;
for (Date date : dates) {
     total = total.add(BigInteger.valueOf(date.getTime()));
}
BigInteger averageMillis = total.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(dates.size()));
Date averageDate = new Date(averageMillis.longValue());
```

Comment: For a long seconds to overflow you would need millions of them (about 7 million would do it)

Answer (score 2):

With a lot of dates, taking the sum of all dates together will certainly go into an overflow. If you want to prevent that you should do it like this (in pseudo code):

```
var first = dates.getFirst
var sumOfDifferences = 0
loop over all dates
    for each date sumOfDifferences += date - first
var averageDate = first + sumOfDifferences/countOfDates
```

This will never make you run in an overflow.

Comment: The expectation this solution will work is based on two assumptions: (1) the dates are near each other in time (2) you don't have a bajillion dates. If either of these assumptions is invalid you may need to use BigIntegers.

Answer (score 0):

There's already an answer here: [Sum two dates in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067657/sum-two-dates-in-java)

You just need to sum up all your date objects using `getTime()` and then divide it by the number of objects and convert it back to a `Date` object. Done.

Comment: Yeah but that involves dividing large long numbers. What if that messes up?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overflow in caluclation of average time:

first sort by date;
store value of first date in `time0`;

Caluclate the average of the deltaTimes by subtractiong first time0 from all times.
Then sum up and divide.

The result = `new Date(time0 + avgDeltas)`;

Comment: how should the dates be sorted? earlier-to-later or the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In here each date convert to long value my `getTime()`. This will return mil-second value. Then we can proceed.

```
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mma");
    Date date1=sdf.parse("7:40AM");
    Date date2=sdf.parse("7:50AM");
    long date1InMilSec=date1.getTime();
    long date2InMilSec=date2.getTime();
    System.out.println("Average "+sdf.format((date1InMilSec+date2InMilSec)/2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Once java 8 is published, you can use

```
Date avgDate = new Date( LongStream.of(datesAsLongArray).sum() / datesAsLongArray.length * 1000);
```