# Getting average value from List of Date

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of Date objects and want to get the average value from this list. Is there a simple way to do this with lambda expressions ?

For example if I my list contains two dates :

```
01/01/2017

31/01/2017
```

The result will be:

```
15/01/2017
```

## Solution

```
Date averaging = Stream.of(date("2017-01-01"), date("2017-01-31"))
            .map(Date::getTime)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.averagingLong(Long::longValue),
                    it -> new Date(
                            (it.longValue() - TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1))
                                    / TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)
                                    * TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1)
                    )
            ));
```

Comment: Could you validate my answer please ?

Answer (score 1):

assuming your Dates are in a list and java8 is an option:

```
long ave = (long) myList.stream()
                    .mapToLong(Date::getTime)
                    .average()
                    .getAsDouble();
System.out.println(new Date(ave));
```

---

using Java Time API

```
List<LocalDate> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(LocalDate.of(2017, 01, 01));
myList.add(LocalDate.of(2017, 01, 31));
myList.forEach(System.out::println);

long ave = (long) myList.stream()
            .mapToLong(x -> x.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli())
            .average()
            .getAsDouble();
System.out.println(new Date(ave));
```

the output:

> Mon Jan 16 00:00:00 CET 2017

Comment: I've tried this for the example that I posted above, and unfortunately it gives me 01/01/2017

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `getTime()` in a date type you have date in milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT, do that for each of your date, add all the millisecond and divide by the length of the array. Then take you number (for exemple: 1495201767023 for now) and create a new date. `Date date = new Date(1495201767023L)` (don't forget the L) It should works

As says in comment, dealing with such Long may cause overflow. So try to divide by constant or do average incremmentivly

Comment: Adding that many dates may cause overflow (milliseconds will be very long numbers). Either divide them by constant (less accurate but shouldn't matter as milliseconds is very precise anyway) or only add two at a time and incrementally take averages.

Comment: Didn't think of that but not a bad point, thanks for the precision

Comment: Just calculated. Overflow after 6168647 adds.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think it's the same idea as the QA marked in the comment [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193177/get-average-of-two-java-util-date)