# Add two String Times in java

Tags: java

I have two String times

```
1:30:00
1:35:00
```

Is there a simple way to add these two times and get a new time which should be something 
`3:05:00`?

I want to do this at client side , so if i can avoid any date liabraries

Comment: Are those times? Are they durations? Are they intervals? Check out `jodatime`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep in mind that you can convert int values for hours/minutes/seconds to a single int like this:

```
int totalSeconds = ((hours * 60) + minutes) * 60 + seconds;
```

And convert back:

```
int hours = totalSeconds / 3600;  // Be sure to use integer arithmetic
int minutes = ((totalSeconds) / 60) % 60;
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
```

Or you can do arithmetic piecemeal as follows:

```
int totalHours = hours1 + hours2;
int totalMinutes = minutes1 + minutes2;
int totalSeconds = seconds1 + seconds2;
if (totalSeconds >= 60) {
  totalMinutes ++;
  totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;
}
if (totalMinutes >= 60) {
  totalHours ++;
  totalMinutes = totalMinutes % 60;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
String time1="0:01:30";
String time2="0:01:35";

SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

Date date1 = timeFormat.parse(time1);
Date date2 = timeFormat.parse(time2);

long sum = date1.getTime() + date2.getTime();

String date3 = timeFormat.format(new Date(sum));
System.out.println("The sum is "+date3);
```

Ouput : `The sum is 00:03:05`

Comment: timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); important if you are using in android

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFormat  to parse the Strings then you can add the hours minutes and seconds

something like

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  d1 = df.parse("1:30:00");
  d2 = df.parse("1:35:00");

Long sumtime= d1.getTime()+d2.getTime();
```

you can see this here as well it looks like possible duplicate of [#####](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067657/sum-two-dates-in-java)

or if you want to use Calender API, then you can also do it using Calender API, then u can do something like

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
     Calendar cTotal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    cTotal.add(c1.get(Calendar.YEAR), c2.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    cTotal.add(c1.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)), c2.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)); // Months are zero-based!
    cTotal.add(c1.get(Calendar.DATE), c2.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

Comment: @junaidp so have you tried

Answer (score 0):

Just sum them as you sum numbers in 1st-2nd grades, going backwards through them.
Also make sure you move over digits to higher register when needed (i.e. not
always when reaching 10 but when reaching 24 or 60 for hours/minutes).
So I suggest you code this algorithm yourself.