# Having trouble adding times to generate time list

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate a time list in Java. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560353/add-two-string-times-in-java) as to how to add two times together. I wrote the code using floats before converting to using times so I know that the general format of the code works. This is the code that I'm having difficulty with:

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String time = "09:00";
        String quarterHour = "00:15";
        String halfHour = "00:30";
        String quarterHour3 = "00:45";
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date times;
        Date temp;
        long sum;


        try {
            times = timeFormat.parse(time);
            while(times.before(timeFormat.parse("15:15"))){
                System.out.println("Timelist: " + time);
                if((times.equals(timeFormat.parse("10:15"))) || (times.equals(timeFormat.parse("13:45")))){
                    temp  = timeFormat.parse(halfHour);
                    sum   = times.getTime() + temp.getTime();
                    time  = timeFormat.format(new Date(sum));
                    times = timeFormat.parse(time);
                }
                else if(times.equals(timeFormat.parse("11:45"))){
                    temp  = timeFormat.parse(quarterHour3);
                    sum   = times.getTime() + temp.getTime();
                    time  = timeFormat.format(new Date(sum));
                    times = timeFormat.parse(time);
                }
                else{
                    temp  = timeFormat.parse(quarterHour);
                    sum   = times.getTime() + temp.getTime();
                    time  = timeFormat.format(new Date(sum));
                    times = timeFormat.parse(time);
                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The result I get from that is simply 09:00. It goes through the loop once and ends.

I followed it through the debugger and what's happening is that when it adds the quarterHour to times it adds 12:15 and not the 00:15 as it's supposed to.

This seems to have something to do with me using 24 hour time as when I change the:

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
```

to:

```
SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
```

It works - except that it goes into an eternal loop.

Question: How do I get it to add only 15 minutes to the time while using 24 hour format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your code:

```
timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

immediately after you declare `timeFormat`.

It fixes your problem on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), or if you're using Java 8 you might use the new `java.time` classes like

```
String timeStr = "09:00";
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
try {
    LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
            Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeFormat.parse("15:15").getTime()),
            ZoneOffset.ofHours(0));
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeFormat.parse(timeStr)
            .getTime());
    LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant,
            ZoneOffset.ofHours(0));
    while (time.isBefore(endTime)) {
        time = time.plus(15, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
        Instant output = time.atZone(ZoneOffset.ofHours(0)).toInstant();
        System.out.println(timeFormat.format(Date.from(output)));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

or, with the `Calendar` like

```
String timeStr = "09:00";
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
try {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(timeFormat.parse(timeStr));
    Date when = timeFormat.parse("15:15");
    while (cal.getTime().before(when)) {
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
        System.out.println(timeFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```