# How to sum between two times?

Tags: java, time

How to sum between two different Times with java. For example, I have this:

```
 t1 = 10:03:45
t2 = 03:00
t3 = 01:12

==> Sum= 10:07:57
```

Here is my essay of the code;

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss"); 
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 

    Time t1 = new Time(formatter.parse("10:03:45").getTime());
    Time t2 = new Time(formatter.parse("03:00").getTime());
    Time t3 = new Time(formatter.parse("01:12").getTime());


    Long sum= formatter2.parse(t1.toString()).getTime() +(formatter.parse(t2.toString()).getTime() + formatter.parse(t3.toString()).getTime());

    System.out.println("***** gettime t1 "+formatter2.parse(t1.toString()).getTime()); // -2997000
    System.out.println("******* gettime t2 "+formatter.parse(t2.toString()).getTime()); // -3597000
    System.out.println("******* gettime t3 "+formatter.parse(t3.toString()).getTime());  // -3599000

    System.out.println("-----------Sum with time "+formatter2.format(total)); // 22:10:07
    System.out.println("-----------Sum "+sum); //-10193000
```

I did not understand why it displays the negation of Time and also the total is not correct.

Thank you for helping me find the exact total of the Times,

Comment: You'd be much better off using `java.time` or Joda Time if you're pre Java 8.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560353/add-two-string-times-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067657/sum-two-dates-in-java also

Comment: @lexicore I know the use of `java.time`.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking!"*

Comment: I’d use the `Duration` class from java.time for the times. It has a `plus` method for adding. The challenge is converting your time strings to `Duration` objects. `Duration.parse` accepts an ISO 8601 syntax like `PT10H03M45S`. You may use `String.replaceFirst` with a regular expression to convert your strings into ISO 8601. Then the ends should meet.

Comment: `java.sql.Time` is for a time of day, not for a duration, that is, not for anything that it makes sense to sum. So I wouldn’t use that. It is also long outdated.