# Java Subtract 2 duration in HH:MM:SS

Tags: java, date

I have 2 string in java (HH:MM:SS) please take note this is **not time**, but **duration**, i used end time - start time to get these values:

Case1:

duration1 = "12:04:45";

duration2 = "13:04:45";

**Expected result: duration1 - duration 2 = "-1:00:00"  (Note that there is negative)**

Case2:

duration1 = "15:13:32";

duration2 = "12:04:45";

**Expected result: duration1 - duration 2 = "3:08:47"**

How can i do that? My attempt for the Case1 (codes modified from [Java add dates of format dd:HH:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786098/java-add-dates-of-format-ddhhmmss)):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");    

String s1 = "12:04:45";
String s2 = "13:04:45";

Date d1 = format.parse(s1);
Date d2 = format.parse(s2);

int sec = d1.getSeconds() - d2.getSeconds();
int min = d1.getMinutes() - d2.getMinutes();
int hr = d1.getHours() - d2.getHours();

Time sum = new Time(hr, min, sec);
System.out.println(sum);  // Output: 23:00:00   which is wrong
```

Comment: I´d say there is no `-1` o clock. You could do it manually by splitting the string s by `:` and subtracting the parsed integers.

Comment: @user3172596
but that is not time, is duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LocalTime or date calculations like some people suggest doesn't work if your period involved more than 24 hours since that doesn't fit in a day.

If you don't have Java 8, you can use JodaTime. I've just checked that this code also works with JodaTime 1.6.2, which is the last version that still works with JDK 1.4.2.

```
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroAlways().minimumPrintedDigits(2)
        .appendHours().appendSuffix(":").appendMinutes().appendSuffix(":").appendSeconds()
        .toFormatter();
Period period1 = formatter.parsePeriod("12:04:45");
Period period2 = formatter.parsePeriod("13:04:45");
Period difference1 = period1.minus(period2).normalizedStandard();
System.out.println(formatter.print(difference1));

Period period3 = formatter.parsePeriod("15:13:32");
Period period4 = formatter.parsePeriod("12:04:45");
Period difference2 = period3.minus(period4).normalizedStandard();
System.out.println(formatter.print(difference2));
```

Output:

```
-01:00:00
03:08:47
```

JodaTime:

- Version 1.6.2 source: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases/tag/v1.6.2
- Version 1.6.2 Maven Jar artifact: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/1.6.2

Comment: can i use this library for java version "1.4.2"

Comment: For JodaTime 2.0 and higher you need JDK 1.5 or higher. I don't think the Period class is in 1.6.2 (the last version that works with JDK 1.4) but I'll check

Comment: @user3172596 I just checked but this works with 1.6.2 as well so you can use it with jdk 1.4.2

Comment: Correct answer, and Joda-Time is always better than using the old troublesome date-time classes. One further suggestion: Use the [standard ISO 8601 format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) rather than the Question’s format that is so easily confused with a time-of-day. Joda-Time uses the standard format by default for both parsing and generating a String representation. Format is `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` where `P` marks beginning and `T` separates the years-months-days portion from hours-minute-seconds. Ex: `PT3H8M47S`.

Comment: @Erwin Bolwidt thanks! btw, if duration 1 is 12:03:32, duration is 12:04:39, using duration1- duration2 will get 00:-01:-07, is there any formatting for joda so i can show -00:01:07 ?

Answer (score 2):

With the Java time API you could use a `Duration` to calculate the duration and format it as you want:

```
String s1 = "12:04:45";
String s2 = "13:04:45";
LocalTime t1 = LocalTime.parse(s1);
LocalTime t2 = LocalTime.parse(s2);

Duration d = Duration.between(t2, t1);
System.out.println(d); //PT-1H
```

If you want to print it as `-1:00:00` you will need to tweak the output format. It could look like this:

```
private static String toHHMMSS(Duration d) {
  long hours = d.toHours();
  int minutes = (int) (d.toMinutes() % 60);
  int secs = (int) (d.getSeconds() % 60);

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + secs;
}
```

Comment: is this api available in JDK 1.4? seems like not

Comment: No, only since Java 8

Answer (score 0):

Use [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to calculate the time difference.
You can query each field and/or format as a time string as this example shows:

```
private Calendar getTimeDiffDate(Date d1, Date d2) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date(d1.getTime()-d2.getTime()));
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 

    // Format as a time string:
    String formattedTime = formatter.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println("formattedTime: "+formattedTime);

    // Query by each field:
    System.out.println("Hours: "+c.get(Calendar.HOUR));
    System.out.println("Minutes: "+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    System.out.println("Seconds: "+c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    return c; 
}
```

Comment: date1 = 12:04:45, date2 = 13:04:45, date1-date2 = 11 hrs using your method

Comment: I get one hour with  
date1 = 12:04:45, date2 = 13:04:45

Comment: Try with new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss") and see if that helps