# Formatting time only in java - from a text file

Tags: java

I want to read time from text in java but when it read a time in (hh:mm) formate as example below:

04:15 and 04.12.2014

and there is my java code to convert the string to Data formate

```
DateFormat timeFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
 .
 .
flight.setArrTime((Date) timeFormat.parse((String)    strTokenizer.nextElement()));
flight.setFlightDate((Date) dateFormat.parse((String) strTokenizer.nextElement()));
```

the output is:

```
Thu Jan 01 04:15:00 EET 1970
Thu Dec 04 00:00:00 EET 2014
```

It gives in long format Date, while I want just take timezone (04:15).

What should I do ?

Comment: I guess its because you parse your DateFormat back to Date, or it is a problem of your creating the output.

Comment: You could just add the two dates, using this ugly hack:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067657/sum-two-dates-in-java

Comment: I suggest you put both the time and the date in the same Date object and then output the parts of it you want.

Comment: Thanks friends but I need to read to text time and date.

Comment: Show us the code where the output is created. a Date allways has the "long format" and if you dont force him, to show it otherways, he will keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the date like :

```
String s1 = "04:15";
String s2 = "04.12.2014";
DateFormat timeFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

String newDate1 = timeFormat.format(timeFormat.parse((s1)));
String newDate2 = dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse((s2)));
```

Comment: I read to not string buause I will calculate this time. I want to read time

Answer (score 0):

If i guess right, you hava

```
class Flight{
    Date arrTime;
    Date flightDate;
    public setArrTime(Date date){
    //yourcode
    }
    public setFlightDate(Date date){
    //yourcode
    }

}
```

The DateFormat is not a specific way to store Dates, but only how to output them as strings. So if you Just want to output the Arrival time you can write

```
System.out.println("Der Flug flieg am "+ dateFormat.format(flightTime));
System.out.println("Der Flug kommt um "+ timeFormat.format(arrTime)+ " Uhr an.");
```

But though your informations are time and date you can put then both in the same Date, saving some memory

EDIT:
Maybe you want to make more clear what you want to achieve, because your code does everything, you want. It doesnt create the desired output, maybe, but you dont show us, where your output comes from. I am mostly shure that this is the problem!

Comment: Yes it is correct. I have Flight class and Date arrTime, Date flightDate. I want to read text data like 04:12;04.12.2014. I want to storing in java

Comment: Could you please write this format? flight.setArrTime((Date) timeFormat.parse((String)    strTokenizer.nextElement()));

Comment: your code is correct, if you want to store a Date in your class, just alter your output-method. The other idea would be to Store the desired String instead of a date. That would work too, but would be not as nice :)